# Firebase - Push to pushed data

Tags: javascript, firebase

Here's my data

```
{
  "deck" : {
    "-JkpwAnieKjQVsdtPD4m" : {
      "deck" : "Deck 1",
      "user" : "simplelogin:1"
    },
    "-Jkq4unexm-qwhO_U2YO" : {
      "deck" : "Deck 2",
      "user" : "simplelogin:1"
    },
    "-Jkq5-II1q5yM6w3ytmG" : {
      "deck" : "Deck 3",
      "user" : "simplelogin:6"
    },
    "-Jks5mbMHmPB9MwnnOCj" : {
      "deck" : "Deck 4",
      "user" : "simplelogin:1"
    }
  }
}
```

If I want to add:

```
      cards: {
        "-GeneratedKey":{
          "title":"foo",
          "text":"bar",
        }
      }
```

to say the item with the deck "Deck 2", how do I select that object to push to it. The end result would be:

```
{
  "deck" : {
    "-JkpwAnieKjQVsdtPD4m" : {
      "deck" : "Deck 1",
      "user" : "simplelogin:1"
    },
    "-Jkq4unexm-qwhO_U2YO" : {
      cards: {
        "-GeneratedKey":{
          "title":"foo",
          "text":"bar",
        }
      }
      "deck" : "Deck 2",
      "user" : "simplelogin:1"
    },
    "-Jkq5-II1q5yM6w3ytmG" : {
      "deck" : "Deck 3",
      "user" : "simplelogin:6"
    },
    "-Jks5mbMHmPB9MwnnOCj" : {
      "deck" : "Deck 4",
      "user" : "simplelogin:1"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is what I tried:

```
  deckRef.orderByChild('deckName').equalTo('Deck 2').push({
    card: {
      title: 'foo',
      text: 'bar'
    }
  });
```

but that just returned an error. What do I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`deckRef.orderByChild('deckName').equalTo('Deck 2')` returns a query, not a ref. A query can match many nodes. Even though in your case it only matches one, you will need to first capture that one node into a ref to be able to `push` to it.

```
var query = deckRef.orderByChild('deckName').equalTo('Deck 2');
query.once('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.ref().child('cards').push({
        title: 'foo',
        text: 'bar'
    });
});
```